# SQL SELECT followed by UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

I have Employee table and HR table. Address of employee ( address column ) is there in both the tables. I want to update the HR table's address column with the address from Employee table, for all those records wherever  there is a mismatch between the HR table's address and Employee table's address for the same employee.employee-id is primary key in employee table and foreign key in HR table.

Answer (score 1):

You can still do `JOIN` on `UPDATE` statements.

```
UPDATE  HR a
        INNER JOIN Employee b
            ON a.EmpID = b.ID  -- relationship column
SET     a.address = b.address
WHERE   a.address <> b.address -- to make this query faster
                               -- filter only those address that didn't match
```

Comment: thank you JW. small change ... if i need smthing like lets say along with address, i would also like to update the "Phone No" column, which is also there in both the tables , upon finding a mismatch similar to address.do we ve to separate the SET & Where clause for all corresponding columns in the query, coz address mismatch must not update the phone no.